# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded and an Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function

```
function flicker(length) {
    $("p:nth-child(" + (Math.random() * length) + ")").toggleClass('off');
    setTimeout(flicker(length), Math.random()*1000);
}
```

The code above gives me the error

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I also wanted to know if there is any way to toggle classes with JavaScript when I use

```
document.querySelectorAll("p:nth-child(" + (Math.random() * length) + ")").classList.toggle('off');
```

I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined

How can I resolve these issues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging I have seen 2 issues.

1. `Math.random() * length` returns a float so you need to round.
2. `setTimeout` can accept a function by passing the `length` argument after the delay

> window.setTimeout(func, [delay, param1, param2, ...]);

```js
function flicker(length) {
  $("p:nth-child(" + Math.round(Math.random() * length) + ")").toggleClass('off');
  setTimeout(flicker, Math.random() * 1000, length);
}

flicker(5)
```

```css
.off {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @BenG. How can I get rid of second error. I want to write the code in pure JavaScript for sake of learning.

Comment: the easiest way to see how a jQuery function works, is look at the [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d92310050ca7bf0b33825d64e052f9a8809c3e9e/test/data/jquery-1.9.1.js#L2218)

Comment: Thanks that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap the `flicker(length)` in a function when using setTimout like this:

```
function flicker(length) {
  $("p:nth-child(" + (Math.random() * length) + ")").toggleClass('off');
  setTimeout(function(){flicker(length);}, Math.random()*1000);
}
```

Otherwise it always gets called intantly, resulting in something like this:

```
function foo(){
  foo();
}
foo();
```

which just creates an endless loop and will cause the same stack error as you described.

Comment: Thanks Michael it worked. Is there anything that I can do to resolve the `TypeError`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're calling `flicker()` in an infinite loop by setting the result of it to the `setTimeout`, instead of passing its reference. You need to provide the `setTimeout()` call an anonymous function. Try this:

```
function flicker(length) {
    $("p:nth-child(" + (Math.random() * length) + ")").toggleClass('off');
    setTimeout(function() {
        flicker(length)
    }, Math.random()*1000);
}
```